# Updating fields in text file, shell bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file.

Info in text file is

```
Book1:Author1:10.50:50:5
Book2:Author2:4.50:30:10
```

First one is book name, second is author name, third is the price, fourth is the quantity and fifth is the quantity sold.

I was trying to update the price and it works fine with:

```
read -p $'New Price: ' newPrice
sed "s/${Title}:${Author}:[^:]\+/${Title}:${Author}:${newPrice}/g" BookDB.txt > tempBook.txt
mv -f tempBook.txt BookDB.txt
echo "Book price updated!"
```

When I quit the program and add codes to update the quantity using:

```
read -p $'New Quantity: ' newQty
sed "s/${Title}:${Author}:${Price}:[^:]\+/${Title}:${Author}:${Price}:${newQty}/g" BookDB.txt > tempBook.txt
mv -f tempBook.txt BookDB.txt
echo "Book quantity updated!"
```

The quantity could not be updated simply because I kind of lost the price info. I was able to edit the quantity if I added a new book into the program right away where the price was stored, but for other books, it was impossible to edit the quantity avaliable.

Can someone please help? I was wondering if I could extract/store the value of the price of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For update quantity you can use:

```
read -p $'New Quantity: ' newQty
sed -re "s/${Title}:${Author}:([^:]+):[^:]+/${Title}:${Author}:\1:${newQty}/g" BookDB.txt > tempBook.txt
mv -f tempBook.txt BookDB.txt
echo "Book quantity updated!"
```

Comment: I am new to bash shell scripting. May I ask what does ([^:]+) do? and also [^:] , does \1 takes the value of ([^:]+) ?

Comment: 1) `([^:]+)` is regexp, that matches string containing more then one character and all this characters not a `':'`. 2) Yes.

Comment: 1.5) `[^:]` is regexp, that matches any character except `':'`.